# MBProgressHud and SDWebImagePrefetcher

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, mbprogresshud, sdwebimage

I'm trying to show a custom [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) while downloading a list of URLs with [`SDWebImagePrefetcher`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImagePrefetcher.m) using `NSURLConnection` methods.

`SDWebImagePrefetcher` has a method that, when called, shows in console the progress of the images download.

Now, i would like to show that `NSLog` progress in the custom `MBProgressHUD` and I would like the HUD to stay on screen until the process is done, but I don't know how to do it and plus, when my `NSURLConnection` methods are called, it shows the initial HUD (Connnecting), then quickly jumps to "Complete", even if the images still needs to be downloaded.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Downloading contents..."; //here, i would like to show the progress of the download, but it seems to jump this part
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    //arr = array which holds a plist
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) {
        for (NSDictionary *val in [dict valueForKey:STR_ROWS]) {
            [array addObject:[val objectForKey:@"image"]];
        }
    }

    [prefetcher prefetchURLs:array];

    HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"]] autorelease];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Completed",@"Completed!");
    HUD.detailsLabelText = nil;
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [HUD hide:YES];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection to the remote server failed with error:\n %@\n Try again in a while"),[error localizedDescription]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alertView show];
}
```

I tried to look into the examples, but didn't find out how to do what i want to do.

**EDIT**

HUD Setup:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if (buttonIndex == 0){
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
            switch (internetStatus) {
                case NotReachable:
                {
                    //not reachable
                   break;
                 }
                case (ReachableViaWWAN):
                {
                    //reachable but not with the needed mode
                    break;
                }
                case (ReachableViaWiFi):{
                    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES]retain];
                    HUD.delegate = self;
                    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                    HUD.labelText = @"Connecting...";
                    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/myPlist.plist"];
                    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
                    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                    [connection start];
                    [connection release];
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't show how you set up the HUD. Can you show that?

Comment: Thanks. That didn't turn out to be the issue - I missed that you didn't actually update the progress anywhere! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `connection:didReceiveResponse:` you must record how large the download is,
for example in self.responseSize. Then, in `connection:didReceiveData:` you
must append the data you just got to the data you previously got, and update the progress:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Downloading contents...";
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;

    // Define responseSize somewhere...
    responseSize = [response expectedContentLength];
    myData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [myData appendData:data];

    HUD.progress = (float)myData.length / responseSize; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried do it that way, but the problem is that the HUD does not persist on the screen. I think that it may depend on the requested url, i should request all the images url or?

Comment: If you request many images and have just the one HUD then you may end up hiding / showing up the HUD over and over and not having time to actually show any progress updates, yes. You need to build an abstraction that handles that.

Comment: Practically I'm fetching and storing the images in cache for later usage, but the process runs in background and may slow down the app, so I wanted to show an HUD for the entire process time and then hide it when done

Comment: Then you need to set up the HUD once for the whole batch, and probably update the progress once for each image that is downloaded. So for image N of TOTAL you update `HUD.progress = (float)N / TOTAL;`. How to apply this at a higher level is left as an exercise for the reader. (Or perhaps a topic for a different question?)